Linux input subsystem event codes: double click volume up key
I'm trying to modify this code text for a single button device. I have it working for moving forward a page using the config file:
nextPage EV_KEY KEY_VOLUMEUP 1

Now I would like to update the config file for going to the previous page, but I can't figure out how. The latest code I have tried is:
nextPage EV_KEY KEY_VOLUMEUP 1
prevPage EV_KEY KEY_VOLUMEUP_DOUBLETAP 1

Needless to say, that didn't work. I've lost track of the other variations I've tried. Obviously I don't really know what I'm doing and could use some input. Thanks
Also, I'm working Windows so I haven't been able to use a tool like evtest to see what the inputs are.
I tried various configurations of the prevPage line of the code above. I've also tried understanding linux event codes and looking though https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h.

There is no double click detection in input subsystem. You have to arm timer on first event and either consider event as single click if timer expired, or as double click if the same event came while timer is not yet expired. You can detect even triple/quad/etc clicks, it's up to your code. "Doubletap" mentioned in event library header is different thing, it has nothing to do with click sequences.
